# How to find all files on a Mac with a file name that is illegal on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems, filenames

I'm looking for a script or software which can check all the files on a Mac and report restricted/forbidden characters e.g. \ / : * ? " < > |, with which Windows cannot work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about restricted characters in the file name or the content of the file?

Comment: \ / : * ? " < > | in the filenames. Is there any forbidden characters for file contents?!!! Actually I'm not sure!

Answer (score 3):

For finding file names with problematic characters, you can use find:

```
$ find / -regex ".*[<>/:*?|].*" -print
```

Put all characters you want to look for in the square brackets. Note that some characters must be escaped because they have special meaning (e.g. 0-9 will find all digits, not 0, - and 9). Basically, what you specify in the double quotes is a regular expression which file names must fit in order to be printed.

You can create a file containing the list of all files like so:

```
$ find / -regex ".*[<>/:*?|].*" -print > problematic-files.txt
```

If you use `-name` instead of `-regex`, then you can specify a basic shell pattern (where * stands for any number of characters, ? for one, and [...] of a choice of characters). This is less flexible, but probably enough for your purposes:

```
$ find / -name "*[<>/:*?|]*" -print > problematic-files.txt
```

(I'm not sure if Mac OS has the same find functionality as GNU find, the one I'm using. Use "man find" to get the manual and figure out how to use regular expressions or shell patterns with it).

Comment: Note that the `/` will match paths, like `/some/path/goodname.txt`... Otherwise, this works well on a Mac.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. So leave out the / in the regex. If you need to filter out slashes in filenames, I can't see a solution that doesn't involve running the list of all files on the computer through a scripted loop and using sed on each one; hopefully you don't have too many files with slashes in them. On my system I have trouble actually creating a file with a slash in it's name...

Comment: Your first line of code pretty much flushed my entire hard drive into the console! It's still running as I write. Wow.